# VB.Net how to get Assembly Checksum(SHA1,MD5,SHA256,SHA512) value?

Tags: vb.net, hash

How to get SHA1, SHA256, SHA512, MD5 checksum values itself in vb.net?

i can get my exe file checksum values from 3rd party utilities like Hasher...
but i want to get my own assembly checksum values itself?

please help

Update:1 I tried Myself

```
       Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim _myexe$
    Try
        _myexe$ = IO.Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, My.Application.Info.AssemblyName & ".exe")
        Using _sha512 As New System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512CryptoServiceProvider
            Using stream = File.OpenRead(_myexe$)
                Dim _hash = _sha512.ComputeHash(stream)
                Trace.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(_hash).Replace("-", String.Empty))
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Trace.WriteLine(Err.Description)
    End Try
End Sub
```

is this correct way to get checksum values for current(running) assembly ?

Comment: FYI you can replace the entire `IO.Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, My.Application.Info.AssemblyName & ".exe")` with `Application.ExecutablePath`.

Comment: thank you so much it's getting the assembly path +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [System.Security.Cryptography.MD5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Using md5Hash = MD5.Create()
    Using stream = File.OpenRead(filename) ' file name is your assembly
        Return md5Hash .ComputeHash(stream)
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: thanks "al-3sli" , i have an little doubt, is dat io error coming while execute assembly like file read error or file is using an another process...so on ?..

Comment: @pc8181 : There is always a possibility that an IO error will get thrown. It all depends on whether something else is locking the file or not. Though opening it for reading shouldn't be a problem unless some external program locks the file completely.

Comment: yes i afraid for this, have any other way to get checksum values itself